# Grant command syntax error

Tags: mysql

I get a syntax error when I run this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; There is no "-" at the end.

Comment: I think the extra single qoute was added by stack over flow

Comment: What is the version of MySql?

Comment: 8.0.11 is the MySql version

Comment: * .* there is no space , i added it, since it wasn't displaying in stack overflow.!!

Comment: I think it would help if you could provide the actual content of the error message. (Are you connected to the MySQL database as a user with sufficient privileges to perform this operation? And you are entering this statement at a `mysql>` prompt in the MySQL command line client, and not entering it as a bash command? (I'm just making sure we aren't making assumptions that aren't valid.)

Comment: Cool story bro. Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the as below it should work for you :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to declare your instruction as follows

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

You don´t need to use IDENTIFIED BY instruction because that command corresponds to

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```